# XML Transformation using XSLT filtering

Tags: xslt

Please see the sample XML example below. I need to create an XSL, which will print the name of the table when it has a column name as ROW_TIMESTAMP. For example the below xml should give me the output as DM_MONOFILAMENT and not PT_TEXT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
<schemaMetadataList>
   <schemaMetadata>
       <tableMetadataList>
        <tableMetadata>
          <name>DM_MONOFILAMENT</name>
          <recordCount>0</recordCount>
          <columnList>
            <column>
              <name>ENTERPRISE_ID</name>
              <ordinal>1</ordinal>
              <type>CHAR</type>
            </column>
            <column>
              <name>ROW_TIMESTAMP</name>
              <ordinal>9</ordinal>
              <type>TIMESTAMP</type>
            </column>
        </columnList>
        <name>PT_TEXT</name>
          <recordCount>0</recordCount>
          <columnList>
            <column>
              <name>ENTERPRISE_ID</name>
              <ordinal>1</ordinal>
              <type>CHAR</type>
            </column>
            <column>
              <name>PRACTICE_ID</name>
              <ordinal>2</ordinal>
              <type>CHAR</type>
            </column>
        </tableMetadata>
      </tableMetadataList>
    </schemaMetadata>
  </schemaMetadataList>
</metadata>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XSLT-1.0 stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="text()" />
    
    <xsl:template match="/metadata/schemaMetadataList/schemaMetadata/tableMetadataList/tableMetadata[columnList/column/name='ROW_TIMESTAMP']/name[1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

> DM_MONOFILAMENT